# How open euclideangeometry-man.pdf with texdoc?

Tags: texdoc

This concerns the new `eucldeangeometry` package (version 0.1.5).

If I execute

```
texdoc euclideangeometry-man
```

it opens `euclideangeometry.pdf`(which documents the code) rather than the expected user manual `euclideangeometry-man.pdf`.

What `texdoc` command, if any, will open the user manual file I want?

Comment: Works for me; try `texdoc -l euclideangeometry`, it should list three items from which to choose.

Comment: OK, using the `-l` parameter does the trick. But is there a more direct way to cause `texdoc` to open `euclideangeometry-man.pdf`?

Comment: As I said it works with `texdoc euclideangeometry-man` for me.

Comment: this file is not necessary present. If not, you can save it in any directory from the tree describe with the command "kpsewhich -var-value TEXDOCS". Typically the texmf/doc  directory and its  subdirectories in your HOME directory

Answer (score 1):

If you are a texlive user on a debian-like system, the package texlive-science-docs is buggy. The  documentation files are not in the TEXDOCS search tree.
You can modify it, but the simplest is probably to create symbolic links in your personal TEXDOCS tree.

```
ln -s /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/euclideangeometry/euclideangeometry.pdf ~/texmf/doc/euclideangeometry.pdf
ln -s /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/euclideangeometry/euclideangeometry-man.pdf ~/texmf/doc/euclideangeometry-man.pdf
```

From this way updates are supported.
Otherwise you can copy them in your personal TEXDOCS

Comment: In fact, the file `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/latex/euclideangeometry/euclideangeometry-man.pdf` *is* there, and surely that's part of the `texdoc` file tree. And now with the most recent texlive updates, command `texdoc euclideangeometry-man` does open that user manual.

Comment: @murray Not yet on my Debian/testing box.Updated 2020 feb 18  http://ix.io/2dp3

Comment: I updated TeXLive on my Mac on 2020 Mar 3.